Django Migration Issue With Abstract User
I have created Django application it was working fine at start but now i am facing migration issue with abstract user i remove the migrations files and database  from my project and then remigrate it the issue still exist
Please any one help me to solve the problem

If i am not wrong i suggest you to try migrations in this order.
STEPS

Delete all migrations from apps.
Remove db
Lets say your AbstractUser model is in app accounts and you have other two apps like products and sales
When you user model is abstract, you need to migrate users app first
Example Commands

python manage.py makemigrations accounts products sales
python manage.py migrate 

I hope that will solve your issue.

it's worked for me thanks
